Android Infotainment emulator wifi/mobile data connectivity issue
Cannot able to connect wifi/Internet in Android studio emulator. I have tried multiple solutions which are there in internet but none of them worked for me.
Below is one of the link which I have tried but didn't worked
Android emulator error " Connected to device. Can't provide internet " How to solve?
We are using Microsoft defender, Zscaler maybe because of these applications internet is blocking.
Could you please respond on the same what could be the reason behind this issue.
Thanks in Advance.
